# IntelliJ IDEA stopped offering Run... commands for Scala project after upgrading to 2019.3.3

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, ide, upgrade

Updated IDEA to latest 2019.3.3 (released 1/2 month ago) and Scala project stopped being runnable (tests as well).

Even new Scala project created from scratch is not runnable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending time on examining settings, resetting all configuration, reinstalling IDEA, I somehow saw that *Kotlin* (in *Languages & Frameworks*) can be updated, and clicked *Update*.

Now it is 1.3.70-release-IJ2019.3-1, latest. And now project and tests can be *run*, again.